# efficient way in oracle to check if a value exists is in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to check if a nvarchar value exists in a table. The column name is barcode, currently I am doing the following

```
SELECT COUNT(*)INTO v_tmpBarcodeCount
FROM CONTAINER
WHERE BARCODE = TO_CHAR(v_iTemp);        
IF v_tmpBarcodeCount = 0 THEN...
```

Now I need to check two other tables for this same value in their barcode columns. I could add two more sql statements like above or is there a way to write 1 sql statement that returns true or a count of 1 if the barcode exists in any of the tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` in a `CASE` expression then the database can short-cut the logic if the value is found in the first table (and you do not have to count all the rows, only find the first matching row):

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE value = v_iTemp)
       OR   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE value = v_iTemp)
       OR   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table3 WHERE value = v_iTemp)
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
INTO   v_exists
FROM   DUAL;

IF v_exists > 0 THEN
  ...
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can streamline an SQL query to check for barcode values across multiple tables in a single statement. However, this would be done in a different manner than what you have done previously. Instead of using separate SELECT COUNT(*) statements for each table you can use a combination of UNION and a single SELECT query to check all three tables at once.

Here is what I would do.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_tmpBarcodeCount
FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CONTAINER
    WHERE BARCODE = TO_CHAR(v_iTemp)
    UNION
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE BARCODE = TO_CHAR(v_iTemp)
    UNION
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLE3
    WHERE BARCODE = TO_CHAR(v_iTemp)
);

IF v_tmpBarcodeCount > 0 THEN
    -- Barcode exists in at least one table
    ...
ELSE
    -- Barcode does not exist in any table
    ...
END IF;
```

Notes:

- TABLE2 and TABLE3 should be replaced with the actual names of the other two tables you want to check.
- The UNION operator is used to combine the results from the three SELECT queries. It automatically removes duplicate rows, so if the barcode exists in more than one table, it will still count as 1.
- The SELECT 1 is a simple way to return a row if the condition is met in each table.
- The outer SELECT COUNT(*) then counts the number of rows returned, which will be 1 if the barcode exists in any of the tables and 0 if it does not.

This checks all three tables in a single statement here. Let me know if you have any more questions.